# How to manage JSON-Schemas for multiple projects?

Tags: json, architecture, jsonschema

Suppose you have a Schema that is used in a UI-App (e.g. Vue), a Node.js or Springboot Server and has to validate against Databases (e.g. SQL, mongoDB,...), and maybe some Micro-services running on whatever.

How and where do I manage a this JSON-Schema, so that if I have to change the schema for whatever Reason, that every architectural component can handle the new JSON-Schema(s).
Otherwise I need to update the Schema in up to 10 projects so none is incompatible.

Is it really as simple as having a git project full with just JSON-Schemas or do I need specific loaders for each language/environment?
Are there best practices that I am unaware of?

PS: I don't really think I need the automatically synchronized on runtime, so don't really think I need another Microservice to achieve that.
That being said, if a Microservice is the best way to go, then getting a Microservice it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep them in a git project, how do you load them? Clone the project each time the app starts? It may work, but I would go with a more flexible approach that should take too much effort to be done:

- Build a JSON schema repository accessible via a REST API
- When the app starts, it makes a request to grab the schema (latest, or a specific version)

That way you get an uniform (and scalable) way of playing with the schemas. Even if you think about a hot-reload sometime in the future, you can leverage this approach to do that.

[Here](https://github.com/schema-repo/schema-repo) is an old project in this direction, you may give it a shot to see if it works (or for some inspiration, at least)